# How do I use OMPython or OMShell to get connectors/ports for a component in a model

Tags: python, modelica, openmodelica

I currently work on building a parser from Modelica to a custom JSON structure.

As part of this, I want to use OMPython to extract all connectors/ports for each component in a model. Are there any OpenModelica CLI commands that let me do this?

I built a script that enters the class of each component in the model, and sends back all components in the model that I decide are connectors (e.g. `Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput`). But this requires me to define all possible connector types, and generally it seems like an inefficient method, since there must be some way for OpenModelica to know which connectors a component has (e.g., for the GUI).

I am open to other approaches for retrieving the connectors!

Comment: https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/scripting_api.html#getconnectionlist

Comment: https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/scripting_api.html#isconnector

Comment: @stardust, the `getConnectionList` seems to only be available in version 1.22, which is only in development stage. Btw, I suppose that it considers _connections_ and not _connectors_. The `isConnector` definitely helps define connectors, but still requires me to enter every single component in the model. I was hoping to find a way to avoid entering every component in the model with ANTLR